# close the popup box after submitting the form

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup, popup-balloons, balloon-tip

I'm using jquery.mb.balloon.js, jQuery plugin to add balloon tips in my webpage. I need to close the popup box, after submitting the form.I try hideDuration: 80 method but its not working...

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
data: dataString,
url: baseUrl + "send/",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (result) {

$('#balloon').balloon({hideDuration: 80}); // hide my popup box

},
error: function (result) {
alert(result);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try `$('#balloon').hideBalloon();` instead of `$('#balloon').balloon({hideDuration: 80});`

Comment: yes, but its not working...

Answer (score 0):

try this code if u r using bootstrap modal popup

```
$("#balloon").modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addclass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) function to add hidden class to modal div

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#baloon").hideBalloon({hideDuration:80});
```